# How to delete element from hsearch

Tags: c, search, hash, gnu

I am using hsearch_r function provided by GNU C library.

I see that while i can add elements into the HASH table using hsearch_r and passing the action as ENTER, i see no way to remove an element or an entry from the HASH table.

Does anybody know a reason why this is so?

Can i do the following to implement my delete function.

I first search for it using hsearch_r with the action as FIND. Then once i get a pointer to the hash_element then i free it. Will that work? What good is a hash library if i can only add elements and search for them. Why isnt a delete routine provided?

I tried googling for the source code of hsearch library and couldnt find it. Can somebody also point me to that?

http://linux.die.net/man/3/hcreate_r

EDIT:

I also see that if i call the hsearch_r twice with action ADD then it throws neither an error nor does it update the hash with the new value. This is odd. This means that internally hsearch does NOT implement a replace functionality and we will have to do it ourselves i.e. first do a search and then if it exists, then delete the first entry and then add a new one. However to do this we would need to DELETE an element from the hash, which i am unable to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [source of `hsearch_r`](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.20/hsearch__r_8c_source.html) can be found online.

If the key is in the table, the function returns with the found entry before checking the action, which means that adding an existing key behaves like finding it. (You could overwrite the value of the "found" struct after the call to `hsearch(ADD)` and overwrite old values.)

The implementation isn't suited to element deletion. It maintains an array of buckets. Hash collision is handled by finding another empty bucket, so that the bucket index does not necessarily equal the hash code. When you insert two values with the same hash code, the second will get such a bucket where the hash code is not the bucket index.

When you now delete the first item and then try to find the second, it will not be found, because the "other" buckets are only considered when the "optimum" bucket where the hash code is the bucket index is full.

Besides the non-updating re-additions and the missing deletion option, there are other restrictions to `hsearch_r`. For example, the maximum nuber of entries must be estimated beforehand and cannot be changed later. I think `hsearch_r` is intended as a fast hash table for a limited range of applications. You might be better off with another, more general hash table implementation.

Alternatively, you could use a default data parameter that means "not present". The type of `entry->data` is `void *`, so `NULL` is an obvious choice. The following data is a modification of the man pages's example with wrapper functions that have a more natural syntax than `hsearch_r`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define __USE_GNU
#include <search.h>

#define NIL (-1L)

void hadd(struct hsearch_data *tab, char *key, long value)
{
    ENTRY item = {key, (void *) value};
    ENTRY *pitem = &item;

    if (hsearch_r(item, ENTER, &pitem, tab)) {
        pitem->data = (void *) value;
    }
}

void hdelete(struct hsearch_data *tab, char *key)
{
    ENTRY item = {key};
    ENTRY *pitem = &item;

    if (hsearch_r(item, FIND, &pitem, tab)) {
        pitem->data = (void *) NIL;
    }
}

long hfind(struct hsearch_data *tab, char *key)
{
    ENTRY item = {key};
    ENTRY *pitem = &item;

    if (hsearch_r(item, FIND, &pitem, tab)) {
        return (long) pitem->data;
    }
    return NIL;
}

int main()
{
    char *data[] = { 
        "apple", "pear", "cherry", "kiwi", 
        "orange", "plum", "pomegranate", NULL
    };
    char **p = data;

    struct hsearch_data tab = {0};
    int i;

    hcreate_r(10, &tab);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) hadd(&tab, data[i], i + 1L);

    hdelete(&tab, "pear");
    hadd(&tab, "cherry", 144);

    while (*p) {
        long value = hfind(&tab, *p);

        if (value == NIL) {
            printf("%s: NIL\n", *p);
        } else {
            printf("%s: %ld\n", *p, value);
        }
        p++;
    }

    hdestroy_r(&tab);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: If you use ponters as data and the hash table owns that data, you must `free` the data on destruction, but also when you overwrite existing values.

Comment: @M Oehm, the third argument to `hsearch_r` is the struct that shall contain the return value, right? Then, why are you initializing it to `&item`? ps: I'm a newbie, trying to use hsearch_r

Comment: @venkrao: There is no need to initialise `pitem`; you can pass the address of an uninitialised pointer, because it will be overwritten. So the initialisation to `&item` is confusing, but hot harmful. If `pitem` should be initialised, a better value might be `NULL`.

Comment: @M Oehm, Thanks. I'm observing this strange behavior in my code where, `hsearch_r` is able to `ENTER` elements into the hashtable. But, when I try to `FIND`, the search fails. With more debugging with some print statements, I realized that only the element inserted for the last time is staying in the hashtable. The others are not, or they just got overwritten. I'm finding it difficult to understand why there exists only one element(why it is overwritten) Wondering if you had seen similar behavior, and hope I explained the problem well.

Comment: @venkrao: It's a bit hard to find out without code. Why not ask a question here? Things to check: Does the `ENTER` action indicate success? Is the table large enough? As far as I know, it can't grow. Do you update the key of the input struct? You might inadvertently overwrite the item with the same key.

Comment: @M Oehm, Yes, `ENTER` indicates success. The table is large enough. I update the key of the struct, Yes. I'm inserting new elements, and not overwriting. yes, I'm probably missing something. I posted a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527659/hsearch-r-overwrites-hash-table) Pleas take a look.

Comment: @venkrao: I think all keys must live as long as the `htable` lives. If the keys are allocated, you must keep track of them separately and free them after use. The table doesn't own the data; it just provides an fast loop-up for existing data. As I said in the answer, the applicability of `hsearch` seems to be limited. You might be better off with another hash table implementation.