# memory leaks with hsearch_r in hash read/write

Tags: c

I am reading a small file line by line, and storing the first column as a key, and succeeding columns as various values in different hashes.  I am using advice I got from [How to delete element from hsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971505/how-to-delete-element-from-hsearch) using POSIX hash functions.

However, I cannot read the hash into memory without getting memory errors.

The data I'm reading in is a tab-delimited table:

```
sample  detailed_category   primary disease or tissue   _primary_site   _sample_type    _gender _study
TCGA-V4-A9EE-01 Uveal Melanoma  Uveal Melanoma  Eye Primary Tumor   Male    TCGA
TCGA-VD-AA8N-01 Uveal Melanoma  Uveal Melanoma  Eye Primary Tumor   Male    TCGA
TCGA-V4-A9EI-01 Uveal Melanoma  Uveal Melanoma  Eye Primary Tumor   Male    TCGA
TCGA-VD-AA8O-01 Uveal Melanoma  Uveal Melanoma  Eye Primary Tumor   Male    TCGA
```

and my C program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define GNU_SOURCE
#define __USE_GNU
#include <search.h>//hcreate_r, h*_r
#include <string.h>//strok_r

#define NIL (-1L)
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971505/how-to-delete-element-from-hsearch

void hadd_char(struct hsearch_data *restrict tab, char *restrict key, const char *restrict value) {
    ENTRY item = {key, (char *restrict ) value};
    ENTRY *pitem = &item;

    if (hsearch_r(item, ENTER, &pitem, tab)) {
        pitem->data = (char *restrict ) value;
    }
}

char * hfind(struct hsearch_data *restrict tab, char *restrict key) {
    ENTRY item = {key};
    ENTRY *pitem = &item;

    if (hsearch_r(item, FIND, &pitem, tab)) {
        return (char *) pitem->data;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

    const char PHENOTYPE_FILENAME[] = "head_TcgaTargetGTEX_phenotype.txt";
    FILE *restrict phenotype_fh = fopen(PHENOTYPE_FILENAME, "r");
    if (phenotype_fh == NULL) {
        printf("failed to open %s\n", PHENOTYPE_FILENAME);
        perror("");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *line = NULL;//necessary for reading file
    size_t len = 0;//necessary for reading file
    ssize_t read = 0;//necessary for reading file
    _Bool header = 0;//necessary for reading file
    struct hsearch_data patient_disease = {0};//the hash
    hcreate_r(15, &patient_disease);//bigger than it needs to be
//start reading file
    while ((read = getline ( &line, &len, phenotype_fh)) != -1) {
        if (header == 0) {//skip header
            header = 1;
            continue;
        }
        char *restrict tmp_string = NULL;
        char * tmp_pointer = NULL;
        tmp_string = strtok_r(line, "\t", &tmp_pointer);
        char *restrict patient = strdup(tmp_string);
        unsigned short int column = 1;
        while (tmp_string != NULL) {//read each field in line
            tmp_string = strtok_r(NULL, "\t", &tmp_pointer);
            if (tmp_string == NULL) {
                break;
            }
            column++;
            if (column == 2) {
                printf("patient %s = %s\n", patient, tmp_string);
                hadd_char(&patient_disease, patient, tmp_string);
            }
        }
        free(patient); patient = NULL;
    }

    free(line); line = NULL;
    fclose(phenotype_fh);
//try to get a value back from the hash
    char *restrict x = hfind(&patient_disease, "TCGA-V4-A9EI-01");
    puts(x);
    free(x); x = NULL;
    hdestroy_r(&patient_disease);
    return 0;
}
```

However this segfaults gets errors from valgrind:

```
=17700== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17700==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17700==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 6,144 bytes allocated
==17700== 
==17700== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17700== 
==17700== ERROR SUMMARY: 24 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==17700== 
==17700== 2 errors in context 1 of 2:
==17700== Invalid read of size 1
==17700==    at 0x4C33DA3: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17700==    by 0x4F4BDCA: hsearch_r (hsearch_r.c:171)
==17700==    by 0x108A93: hadd_char (graeme.c:15)
==17700==    by 0x108A93: main (graeme.c:65)
==17700==  Address 0x521d510 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==17700==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17700==    by 0x108AB8: main (graeme.c:68)
==17700==  Block was alloc'd at
==17700==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17700==    by 0x4ECFC99: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==17700==    by 0x108A0B: main (graeme.c:55)
==17700== 
==17700== 
==17700== 22 errors in context 2 of 2:
==17700== Invalid read of size 1
==17700==    at 0x4C33DC7: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17700==    by 0x4F4BDCA: hsearch_r (hsearch_r.c:171)
==17700==    by 0x108A93: hadd_char (graeme.c:15)
==17700==    by 0x108A93: main (graeme.c:65)
==17700==  Address 0x521d511 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==17700==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17700==    by 0x108AB8: main (graeme.c:68)
==17700==  Block was alloc'd at
==17700==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17700==    by 0x4ECFC99: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==17700==    by 0x108A0B: main (graeme.c:55)
==17700== 
==17700== ERROR SUMMARY: 24 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I really like how the author in the linked post added with functions, but I cannot duplicate his success.

in the end, the output should be tested so each key matches the correct value.

How can I successfully read and write from this hash like this?

Comment: Jesus.Can you change the data???

Comment: `free(patient); patient = NULL;` you are freeing patient, but probably the hash table still wants to refer to it. Also: please sanitize your loops, for() loops are easier to read and maintain, IMHO.

Comment: Never cast a `const` to a non-const, `(char *restrict ) value;` is calling for troubles.

Comment: @joop unfortunately removing that line produces even more errors.

Comment: Well, there could be more errors. I stopped reading after spotting the first one.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis I cannot change the data, this is from a publicly available database

Comment: As @Joop already wrote InvalidRead refers to trying to read 1 byte inside a block of 16 that you already have freed.

Comment: How do you test your code , do you have any Unit Test??

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis the testing stage will be verifying that each key matches the correct value, but I haven't gotten there yet

Comment: @Yunnosch Just joking.Medical-data-privacy is a very serious matter?People should be really careful when sharing Medical Data.Well since con is sure that knows what data , shares , I hope he/she doesn't have problem with my humor.

Comment: @con Well Valgrind is a very useful tool that might highlight serious problems.However you need test cases to help Valgrind reach all the potential(negative) of your code.I mean that the test cases are what is going to drive Valgrind throught your code.

Comment: @con Can we please have your header?

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis the C program has no header, and I gave the header for the data file that I read in, is that what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166911/discussion-between-tsakiroglou-fotis-and-con).

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind indicates that you use `strdup` at line 55, here:

```
    char *restrict patient = strdup(tmp_string);
```

and free this string at line 68:

```
    free(patient); patient = NULL;
```

But you passed it (line 65) to `hadd_char()` as the `key` argument:

```
void hadd_char(struct hsearch_data *restrict tab, char *restrict key, const char *restrict value) {
    ENTRY item = {key, (char *restrict ) value};
    ENTRY *pitem = &item;

    if (hsearch_r(item, ENTER, &pitem, tab)) {
        pitem->data = (char *restrict ) value;
    }
}
```

The pointer is copied into an `ITEM`, and `hsearch_r(..., ENTER, ...)` makes a copy of that `ITEM`, including the pointer, and puts it into the hash table.  So when you `free(patient)`, you leave a dangling pointer in the hash table.

You need to arrange that when you insert new data into the hash table, that you keep it alive as long as it's there (this is something that's easier in C++; in C, managing object lifetimes is one of the hardest problems).

Comment: could you please upload the entire program as you ran it? I am still getting segfaults at runtime

Comment: I didn't run it - I just showed how to interpret the Valgrind report that you posted (thanks for doing that - it really helps with understanding the problem).  You might have other bugs too.